# Flow cannot find custom/self published package

Tags: node.js, flowtype, package.json

I have a small node module which uses flow, thus I want to publish it
with the `flowtype` annotations.
Therefore I followed this [npm-flowjs-javascript](https://javascriptplayground.com/npm-flowjs-javascript/) guide.

Basically I used `flow-copy-source` to copy all source files
to my build directory. This works and my build directory contains
the original source files with a ".flow" suffix.
Furthermore I use webpack and babel to bundle everything into an index.js.

Thus my original source folder which looks something like this

```
src/
    index.js
    app.js
    ...
```

is transformed to

```
build/
    index.js
    index.js.flow
    app.js.flow
```

In my package.json I have set the `main` property to `build/index.js`, the `files` property to `["build"]` and the name to `@myname/mymodule`

I then published the package to my npm account with `npm publish`
and installed it in another project with `npm i --save @myname/mymodule`.

In this other project I require the module:

```
import x from "@myname/mymodule"
```

When I transpile everything with babel and run it, the code is correctly executed.
However when I run flow, I get the following error message:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/index.js:6:22

Cannot resolve module @myname/mymodule.

     6│ import frontend from "@myname/mymodule"

Found 1 error
```

Does anybody experiance the same error, or knows what I have done wrong?